# Persian Calendar Regex Date Format

Tags: c#, regex

I found a regular expression for the Persian Calendar in the [link](http://regexlib.com/%28A%284HztpCjjEZpZP8MGOulb9GJ51r9h6YfG83tSVWuz7LF3TcIyDpkrgX3KPrt1vJMzio2hJyLkoucrkq4CvmDvpb9KDbwAbGVTMlSr-9Znir1CJ6ox0PTVaQT8zJk-m0AyHnk_Na_CxAlicu06gi6MfUwXnO_PHWvsdqMOrrhFq_HzJat2OOElwLc_ew72I4d10%29%29/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3262&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) but it is in the `yyyy/MM/dd` format. Any suggestion to format to `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: What do you achieve exactly? Just looking for your string fits with `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` format?

Comment: Actually I got a TextBox and I want to mask it with this regex when they are using Persian Calendar. The TextBox display date format is follow by the system date format, so when a user change the date display format, the TextBox display format also have to change.

Answer (score 4):

```
(?:1[234]\d{2})(\/|\-)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/|\-)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nUMMxzO8XdhkbGjp)

support year between 1200 and 1499

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code and it works well:

First you define a constant like the following code:

```
public const string PersianDateRegex = @"(?:1[23]\d{2})\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
```

so for test it you can use the below code:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(farsiDate, PersianDateRegex))
         {
            ...
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ASP.NET MVC for validation of a Persian date:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^$|^([1۱][۰-۹ 0-9]{3}[/\/]([0 ۰][۱-۶ 1-6])[/\/]([0 ۰][۱-۹ 1-9]|[۱۲12][۰-۹ 0-9]|[3۳][01۰۱])|[1۱][۰-۹ 0-9]{3}[/\/]([۰0][۷-۹ 7-9]|[1۱][۰۱۲012])[/\/]([۰0][1-9 ۱-۹]|[12۱۲][0-9 ۰-۹]|(30|۳۰)))$", ErrorMessage = "Not Valid")]
```